# Android Studio 4.1 - Can't connect debugger to process

Tags: android-studio, debugging

I am unable to attach debugger to my process. I am using Ubuntu 20. Before the new AS 4.1 everything was working. AS finds the process just fine, but when I click "OK" the breakpoint doesn't turn green and I don't see the debugger window/tab.

I don't have much information I can give about this issue, so if you need some log or I don't know what, please let know.

Answer (score 0):

ok, turns out it was a really silly mistake on my part. There is a new drop down "Use Android Debugger Settings from:" which was set up wrong for me and therefore the debugger never attached... Hope that helps to someone